# How to track video tracking through omniture in android

Tags: android, adobe-analytics

In my application I am implementing video tracking.  I have used the following code

```
public static void Videotracking (String AppState,String Mappingevent1,String Mappingevent2,String Mappingevent3)

{   

ADMS_MediaMeasurement mediaMeasure = ADMS_MediaMeasurement.sharedInstance();
Hashtable<String, Object> milestoneMapping = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
milestoneMapping.put(Mappingevent1, "event9");
milestoneMapping.put(Mappingevent2, "event10");
milestoneMapping.put(Mappingevent3, "event11");

Hashtable<String, Object> contextDataMapping= new Hashtable<String, Object>();
contextDataMapping.put("a.media.milestones", milestoneMapping);
contextDataMapping.put("a.media.name", "eVar29,prop29");
contextDataMapping.put("a.media.segment", "eVar55");
contextDataMapping.put("a.contentType", "eVar5"); //note that this is not in the .media namespace
contextDataMapping.put("a.media.timePlayed", "event26");
contextDataMapping.put("a.media.view", "event8");
contextDataMapping.put("a.media.segmentView", "event25");
contextDataMapping.put("a.media.complete", "event12");
mediaMeasure.contextDataMapping =contextDataMapping;  
mediaMeasure.trackVars="evar57,evar58,evar59";
mediaMeasure.trackMilestones=Mappingevent1+","+Mappingevent2+","+Mappingevent3;
}
```

but I'm unable to find when to send these dat to server at the start of the video or on completion and it sends two requests instead of one request when i call this method;

Please help if any implement video tracking.

Answer (score 1):

This document outlines the process to track video in Android: http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/android/index.html#Video_Measurement_Quick_Start

It looks like you've got half the code that configures the tracking, but are missing the actual calls:

```
function startMovie(){  
    mediaMeasure.open(mediaName,mediaLength,mediaPlayerName);
    playMovie();    
}

function endMovie(){
    stopMovie();
    mediaMeasure.close(mediaName);
}
```

Comment: I have used above methods also to track code  at various time intervals .Thanks for answer